# Publish .NET Maui Preview 14 to App Store and Google Play

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

Is it possible to publish a .NET Maui app to Apple AppStore and Google Play or do we need to wait till .NET Maui is finalized?

Comment: whether or not its possible, it seems like a really bad idea to publish a production app based on a pre-release framework

Comment: Agreed. I was just curious though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, you absolutely can, while it's not officially recommended for obvious reasons. However, I do know of .NET MAUI apps that are already in the store today.

Technically it is definitely possible, mostly because at that level a .NET MAUI app isn't much different from a Xamarin.Forms or even regular iOS or Android app. It's still a .ipa or .aab file that needs to be produced.

I have been looking into the process of creating something distributable. You can find my writeups here for [Android](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4377), [iOS](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4397) and from those you can find the links on there for Windows and macOS if that is what you need.

Additionally I made videos about them which you can find here for [Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfSVb_RR7X0) and for [iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpZi5xAvpZA) and lastly the one for [Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNwv_W3TtSU). The one for macOS is not there yet at the time of writing.

Ideally we want to make it all work through `dotnet publish` at some point in the future, but we're not quite there yet. Same story for a UI for doing this within Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Will RC1 be considered the green light for us to go to production? I realize it’s all up to developers and their threshold for risk but I want to get a feel for the .NET Maui team’s perspective.